# Remove duplicates from XML and then save as XML file

Tags: c#, duplicates, xml

I got this code printing all the IDs with latest timestamp. But i would like to remove the elements who isnt the latest timestamp and then save as XML file. There is plenty more attributes then ID and timestamp so i would like to remove those who isnt latest timestamp.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XElement xelement = XElement.Load("data.xml");
    var employees = xelement.Elements()
                .Select(e => new
                {
                    Name = e.Element("Employee").Value,
                    ChangeTimeStamp = DateTime.Parse(e.Element("ChangeTimeStamp").Value)
                })
                .GroupBy(e => e.Name)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    Name = g.Key,
                    ChangeTimeStamp = g.Max(e => e.ChangeTimeStamp)
                });
    foreach (var employee in employees)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", employee.Name, employee.ChangeTimeStamp);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

}

I would like to create xml file with all unique IDs with latest timestamp and all other attributes.

Comment: PLease provide your data.xml

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var xelement = XElement.Load("data.xml");
    var employees = xelement.Elements()
        .Select(e => new
        {
            Element = e,
            Name = e.Element("Employee").Value,
            ChangeTimeStamp = DateTime.Parse(e.Element("ChangeTimeStamp").Value)
        })
        .GroupBy(e => e.Name)
        .Select(g => 
        {
            var maxTimestamp = g.Max(e => e.ChangeTimeStamp);
            foreach (var e in g)
            {
                if (e.ChangeTimeStamp < maxTimestamp)
                {
                    e.Element.Remove();
                }
            }

            return new
            {
                Name = g.Key,
                ChangeTimeStamp = maxTimestamp
            };
        });     

    xelement.Save(yourPathToSave);
}
```

Comment: It doesnt delete in the xml file, is there a way to overwrite the old xml file with only elements with latest timestamp?

Comment: @Girre do you save your new xml later on?

Comment: Well, that the point. I tried this one  xelement.Save("data.xml"); but i guess thats not coreect since it aint working. Ive been looking into the xml file now and it seem like all the elements i wanted to remove have got value of the first employee instead. I want to remove full parent if timestamp is outdated.

Comment: @Girre, it's rather hard to help you when you don't even post the content of your xml file.

Comment: Right now, files match in notepad++ compare pluging. So nothing changed after i run the code. If the element is outdated i want to remove that parent.

Comment: @Girre in your xml you have 3 employees with different names. But you're trying to group them by name. Is it intended? Do want to keep the last record for each employee or you want to keep only the last one for all of them?

Comment: I want the last record for each employee id

Comment: @Girre then your xml is irrelevant, it has no records to remove.

Comment: Hmm Thats correct i think i gave you the wrong one hehe. Then i think it acctuly works! :)

Comment: Now i added this small text into data.xml:       <Employee>
  <Employee>2147483647</Employee>
  <EffectiveDate>1967-08-13</EffectiveDate>
  <ChangeTimeStamp>2014-10-26T21:33:52.12679</ChangeTimeStamp>
  <AccountNumber>String</AccountNumber>
       </Employee> And the DataOut is still keeping both values. It should only keep this one

Comment: @Girre, it's the same as the one you already have. I've changed a timestamp to 2014-10-26T21:33:53.12679 and checked, my code works as required.

Comment: Yepp my fault, had 2 posts with identical timestamps thats why i thought it didnt work. But it works perfectly! Thanks! :)